# toyota fortuner

Tags: electrical

i would like to ask about my toyota fortuner 2009 i checked the obd port and all wirings i also tried a new ecm but it still does not communicate with my scanner i tried different scanners but still cant read the ecm and i cant delete my check engine light i would love to hear  your experience about this ive already spent some time figuring this this problem out but still no success is there anyone can help or give me an idea on how i can fix this issue

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you plug in the tool and turn the car on, do you even see the scan tool trying to connect? IOW, does it try to connect and fail or does it just not try to connect at all?